# How do I find out the exact name of a utility?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

Sometimes I forget the exact name of a tool I'd like to use. Sometimes I remember parts of it, sometimes I only know what it's used for.

Is there a way to find out the name of the program from within the terminal?

E.g. search tool for "window positioning manipulation" -> `wmctrl`

Comment: Read `man apropos`.

Comment: yes that's it. make it an answer and I'll vote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You're looking for `apropos`.**

`apropos(1)` and `whatis(1)` are companions to `man(1)` that search through the descriptions of system programs.  They're often useful in the situation you describe, when you know what you want to do, but don't know the exact name of the program you should use.